# Change SVG font size with a mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm trying to change the size of a SVG text using this:

```
$("#text"+x).click(function(){
    //$(this).style("font-size", "4");
    document.getElementById("text"+x).setAttributeNS(null, "font-size", "4px");
    //this.attr("font-size", "4px");
    alert('it is I'); 
});
```

You can see most of my failed attempts right there. I get the alert to pop up, but nothing happens and no error message.
I've searched the web and Stack Overflow to no avail...
I'm using JS + Jquery!

Any hints are welcomed!
Cheers!

Comment: Could you please produce a runnable code snippet or link a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code. check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/L46vjdyw/). you need to set `font-size` as attribute.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#text"+x).on('click',function(){
    $(this).attr("font-size", "50");
    alert('it is I'); 
  });
 });
```

or if you are adding svg element dynamically  use below code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).on('click',"#text"+x,function(){
      $(this).attr("font-size", "50");
      alert('it is I'); 
    });
 });
```

Comment: Hi again!
Yeap, youe example is working but I cannot make it work on my end ;) No clue about it. I checked the attribute of the text and did all like you have, I think... I'll put an runnable snippet asap ;) Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I'm CLUELESS!!! 
I just did a quick fiddle and it is working!!! But on the main project it doesn't!!! Any ideas? How to debug this?
https://jsfiddle.net/jsantos_pt/vbd4u6bd/3/

Comment: what is 'x' here? are you create svg element dynamically ?

Comment: can you share fiddle with you full code . how you take 'x' ?

Comment: x is just from a for loop I'm running... because I need to change segments of a word.

Comment: @JoaquimSantos can you shot me that code ? means svg element + your loop ?

Comment: Solved! My bad! N00b mistake! I was having the word segment with 0 opacity so the user wouldn't see it and forgot to apply it on click :/ THANKS for all your help man!